# Why is Monero GUI missing November 5th 2017

Tags: history

I am having a very hard time understanding why a standard calendar cannot be implemented into the Monero GUI. I've updated to the newest version (v0.11.1.0) and still cannot select November 5th 2017 in the History. This date also happens to be when I was supposed to receive a deposit and no matter how much I scan the blockchain I cannot get my balance updated.

What the heck is going on and HOW DO YOU RECEIVE MONERO?

[image]

Comment: The Monero balance finally has updated and is showing the correct amount, the daemon had to re-sync. The calendar numbers are still messed up.

Comment: From talking to a friend... this could be an Easter egg related to the movie V for Vendetta...